# MySQL - Multiple index with join and where query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sha256` BINARY(32) NOT NULL,
    `state` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_ignored` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `sha256` (`sha256`)
);
```

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM table2 
JOIN table1 ON table1.sha256 = table2.sha256
WHERE table1.is_ignored = FALSE AND table1.state = 1
```

`table2` has 20m rows indexed by sha256.

`table1` has 5m rows.

I am considering how to index `table1` (not many inserts).

1. Will creating an index of `sha256_state_is_ignored` index increase performance for this query comparing to 3 separate indexes on each the columns?(sha256 index is very dominant here)
2. Will it change if I make the combined index as `state_sha256_is_ignored` instead of `sha256_state_is_ignored`.(thats because sha256 already has an index from his unique index)

**EDIT:**

This is my final table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS maint.files_state_global (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sha256` BINARY(32) NOT NULL,
    `source` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-default(cloud), 1-dynamic compsInOrg and vt',
    `state` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-unknown, 1 - white, 2- black',
    `is_ignored` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `date_in` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_seen` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `sha256` (`sha256`),
    INDEX `source` (`source`),
    INDEX `is_ignored` (`is_ignored`),
    INDEX `last_seen` (`last_seen`),
    INDEX `state_is_ignored_sha256` (`state`, `is_ignored`, `sha256`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

- I must have a single index on source/last_seen/sha256.
- sha256 is unique.
- state and is_ignored must have index and will always come together(90% of the cases with sha256 as well).

So other then changing the `sha256` to `PK` and removing `id`, are my indexes optimized?

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE table1.is_ignored = FALSE AND table1.state = 1
```

says to start a composite index with those two columns (in either order).  Then, looking at the rest of the `SELECT`, I see only `sha256` being mentioned.  So, you may as make a "covering" index:

```
INDEX(is_ignored, state, sha256);
```

Meanwhile, get rid of `id`, assuming it is not really used elsewhere.  This will

1. shrink the disk footprint, thereby helping performance,
2. get rid of a unique index, thereby helping insert performance.

This leads to

```
PRIMARY KEY(sha256)
```

Meanwhile, `table2` needs an index (possibly the PK) starting with `sha256`.

But... Digests (such as sha256) and UUIDs are terrible for performance due to their randomness.  Once the size of those two tables becomes more than your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, performance will go downhill.  SSDs will help *some*.  More RAM will help a lot.  but you won't get much past 1K queries/sec.

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on building indexes.

Comment: remove id?? isnt every table should have running id as PK?

Comment: A PK is necessary, but an `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not.  I went on to suggest replacing `id` with `sha256` as the PK.  Perhaps you are using `JOINing` via `id`?

Comment: no, id is only for auto_inc

Comment: I updated my table to my actual table, other then the sha256 to PK, are the indexes optimized for your opinion?

Comment: Don't bother indexing flags (`is_ignored`); such indexes are unlikely to be used.  An index is optimized _for a query_; without seeing the  rest of the queries, I cannot further answer your question.  For example, if no query uses `source` in `WHERE`, then that index is unnecessary.  If, on the other hand, all such queries _also_ filter on `is_ignored`, then the index could be composite.  Etc.

Comment: Yea, so I took your advice about `is_ignored`, sound logical

Answer (score 0):

My view is that `sha256_state_is_ignored` index will improve performance as this index will become a covering index and the a second lookup on large table to fetch values for `state` and `is_ignored` won't be required.

Having `state` as a prefix won't be as beneficial due to low cardinality.

Comment: But...  Without `state` and `is_ignored` _first_ in the index, the _entire_ index must be scanned to do the filtering!  "Cardinality" is a very tenacious myth.